# Control the services in Azure SF application

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric

My azure SF application has two services. When I deploy the application to the local cluster, is it possible to deploy only one of the services, rather than both (services)?

Comment: Basically, i want to dynamically control the service which should be deployed with the application, something like a runtime parameter to a program.

Comment: I suggest you add that information to your question by clicking on edit at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control this very explicitly.

In your ApplicationManifest you get a number of DefaultServices added, these are autogenerated from the Services added to you Application. When you deploy from Visual Studio (or VSTS) you (implicitly) use the `Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1` script that is automatically added to your Application project. This script does many things at the same time. Namely:

1. Reads and parses publisher profile files to get the parameter values for the selected target (e.g. Cloud, Local1Node, Local2Node, etc.)
2. Upload a new image version to the cluster image store for the *ApplicationType* with a new version number.
3. Create or upgrade an application instance based on the new image and version and create or upgrade an instance for each DefaultService in the ApplicationManifest

Now, you can do all of these steps yourself, and specifically, you can choose which services to spin up instances for.

You can use either the [PowerShell (or CLI)  cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/?view=azureservicefabricps) or use [FabricClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.fabric.fabricclient?view=servicefabric-5.5.216) through .NET code.

What you need to do then is (for PowerShell but similar for FabricClient) is:

- Connect to the cluster [Connect-​Service​Fabric​Cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/Connect-ServiceFabricCluster?view=azureservicefabricps)
- Copy the application package to the cluster with [Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/copy-servicefabricapplicationpackage?view=azureservicefabricps)
- If it is a new - register the application type with [Register-​Service​Fabric​Application​Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/register-servicefabricapplicationtype?view=azureservicefabricps)
- -or- upgrade an existing with [Start-​Service​Fabric​Application​Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/start-servicefabricapplicationupgrade?view=azureservicefabricps)
- For each service you want to create an instance for (yes, you can create multiple instances of the same service inside the same application, and this is not the same as *instances* for a StatelessService) using [New-​Service​Fabric​Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/New-ServiceFabricService?view=azureservicefabricps)

All though this is (a lot) more work than just using the supplied Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1, it gives you complete control over how and when services are deployed. It is also necessary to do this, if you for instance, want to run multiple tenants for the same application on the same cluster, or run multiple versions/environments of the same application on the same cluster (e.g. running Development and Testing on the same cluster)

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate steps and links!  So, when it comes to creating instances, I was wondering if I can ever keep the instance count of a service equal to "0" in the publish profile (keeping other service's instance count as 1) so that one particular service is not deployed, even though it exists in the VS application project.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work, there might be a check that prevents it, although I have not tried that specificaly. There is however a check that prevents you from creating more instances than nodes for instance, so there might be one for this as well... You wont be able to use the same approach for Stateful services though, as you need to determine the partition count for a service at deployment. You should not try to change that after deployment as it would change how the state for that service is persisted across the existing partitions.

Comment: You can also deploy your application without default services, which then requires you to create the services explicitly after creating the application. Look at this example: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-iot/